# How can we show a single disparity map with OpencCV StereoSGBM (C++)?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I'm trying to show a disparity map with stereoSGBM from opencv, but when I show the map, 3 images appear, and I can't find how to show only one disparity map. Here an exemple of what appears (I display it whit the QPixmap class):

[image: The disparity map]

Here is my code :

```
cv::Ptr<cv::StereoSGBM> sgbm = cv::StereoSGBM::create(0, 16, 3);
cv::Mat cv_res;
sgbm->setMode(cv::StereoSGBM::MODE_SGBM_3WAY);
sgbm->compute(left, right, cv_res);
```

Comment: I found that the problem was not here, but in the way used to convert cv::Mat to QPixmap

Comment: How do you convert it to QPixmap ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert the image to Indexed8.